# ADT plugin for eclipse on Windows 7

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

Hi I am new to eclipse and android. Trying to setup the ADE on my Windows 7 laptop.
Eclipse is working fine.
Now I follow the procedure on http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html

Download the ADT Plugin

```
Start Eclipse, then select Help > Install New Software.
Click Add, in the top-right corner.
In the Add Repository dialog that appears, enter "ADT Plugin" for the Name and the following URL for the Location:

https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/

Click OK.
```

*SO FAR SO GOOD*

```
If you have trouble acquiring the plugin, try using "http" in the Location URL, instead of "https" (https is preferred for security reasons).
In the Available Software dialog, select the checkbox next to Developer Tools and click Next.
In the next window, you'll see a list of the tools to be downloaded. Click Next.
Read and accept the license agreements, then click Finish.
If you get a security warning saying that the authenticity or validity of the software can't be established, click OK.
When the installation completes, restart Eclipse.
```

Here I get lost. When I restart Eclipse, ADT is apparently not present, because there is no  *Android App* button under the *File->New* dropdown menu.

Can anybody tell me what to do to get it working?

Answer (score 0):

Try

*File->New->Project->Android->Android Application Project*

Answer (score 0):

It appears you didn't get the welcome screen that the following link mentions when eclipse restarts.
http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html

What you may need to do is go to : Window->preferences; search for android.  There you ought to specify the Android SDK's location on your local disk.  You then can follow the rest of the setup instructions detailed at the above link.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is what my first guess was as well, but I don't see what I should change here. I do have an entry here Android, and the specified location was by default filled in (pointing the location where I installed the android SDK).

Comment: In that case you will need to go to: file->new->project... This should give you a dialog box with Android as an option.  Do you have any of this?